# Is there a way to generate a rails scaffold without the views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

Is there a way to generate a rails scaffold without the views, there has to be a better way then generating the scaffold and deleting the views and the view specs.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `rails g resource Foo bar:text`

Comment: Note it will also do fixtures, yaml and routes.  Fixtures and tests will depend on your testing framework.  You can also do `rails g model...` and rails generate controller... for more restrictive output.

Comment: `rails g resource` is what I was looking for. generating the model and then a controller does not create a RESTful controller.

Comment: `rails g resource` does not generate restful actions inside the controllers.

Comment: @whistler See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37597087/616644) for how to get the RESTful actions auto generated as well.

Answer (score 18):

If you would like to have the controllers generated in the normal fashion, try this:

```
rails g resource Foo bar:text
rails g scaffold_controller Foo --skip-template-engine
```

The first command generates the model and the second one uses the generated model to create the controller which **includes the RESTful actions**.

`--skip-template-engine` causes the views to be omitted.

Comment: This won't work right away because the second command will error out (since you already defined the resource in the first and can't/shouldn't overwrite it just like that). See for a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649519/5925094

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why these answers create the resource first when you can just generate the entire scaffold without the views but still get your controller methods and model.

```
rails g scaffold Foo bar:string --skip-template-engine
```